# favicon for arbitrary content without root access

Tags: apache, .htaccess, favicon

I have a custom `favicon.ico` which I want to have displayed on all pages of a certain site.

For HTML pages, I can do this easily using `<link>`.  Unfortunately, for anything else (say, a PDF)

- there is nowhere to place `<link>`, and
- I'm on a shared server and cannot simply put the icon in the top-level directory to be displayed by default.

I have considered displaying the media within an `<iframe>` to overcome the first difficulty, but would like to avoid this if at all possible.  If the (fairly typical) browser decides to open a non-HTML file using a plugin, my own icon should still be displayed.  But I haven't gotten this to work -- when I view a PDF on my site in Firefox 12.0 I see a favicon, but it's the default one instead of mine.

My question is:  **given the above constraints, can I have a custom `favicon.ico` override the default one and be displayed upon serving up any file on my site?**

For this purpose I tried `AddType` and `RewriteRule` directives in `.htaccess`, but to no avail.  I got the idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886423/favicon-for-pdf-files) and played around with it even though my server doesn't use Drupal.  Maybe that approach would work and I'm just doing something wrong, though.

(I'm excluding images when I say "any file"; many browsers display a thumbnail for them instead of `favicon.ico`, and I'm okay with that.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you planned to have in your .htaccess to deliver a favicon, unless that's that you're asking. Keep in mind a favicon is a seperate request and apache only does stuff with one request, it can't force the user to request another page along side the original request.

So, the answer:
A favicon.ico is the default filename requested by the browser in most cases, but you must follow the rules.

Check out method 2 at http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon.
w3.org are the people who define eveything about the web, so do what this says and you win.

Comment: If I understand correctly, Method 2 is to create **`somesite.com/favicon.ico`** which unfortunately isn't under my control (the closest I can come is **`somesite.com/mypages/favicon.ico`**, which results in their favicon instead of mine showing).  Perhaps I should reword the question to be clearer; but in any case, +10 for trying to help.