# How could I change the favicon on the pdf pages?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on my web and use TCPDF library to produce report. How could I change the favicon on the pdf pages? Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding favicon.ico to root directory of application. New PDFs should automatically use this favicon.

Comment: No problem. Glad I was able to help

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate of [Display favicon for PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886423/display-favicon-for-pdf-files?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)?

Anyways, as that thread says, there is no way to show a favicon in Acrobat Reader, and you should put it in a iframe.